# Copy config file from nuget package to application folder

Tags: azure-devops, nuget-package, build-pipeline

Given:

a) .net core library that contains .json configuration file (not appsettings.json) that is built by azure pipeline and packaged into internal nuget package.

b) .net core application that uses package #a

Problem:

copy .json configuration file from #a into #b's output directory on each build without explicitly adding the file to #b project.

is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found the solution: "PackageCopyToOutput" flag. more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#including-content-in-a-package

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the sharing, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) , it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.